# How to get the last 12 months from the current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with the name of `CouponData` and `Edate` column.

I want to get last 12 months from current date. like from 21-sep-2018 to 01-sep-2017 how its possible using my query?

```
with yearlist as  
( 
select MONTH(GETDATE()) as MONTH 
union all 
select  yl.MONTH - 1 as MONTH 
from yearlist yl 
where (yl.MONTH  - 1 <= MONTH(GetDate())) and  (yl.MONTH - 1 >=   MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH ,-8,GETDATE()))) 
) 
Select  month,(Select IsNull(Sum(BillAmount),0) from CouponData Where month(EDate) = YL.month) 
as Collection,(Select IsNull(Sum(AdultsQty+ChildQty),0) from CouponData Where month(EDate) = YL.month) 
as PaxTotal  from yearlist YL order by MONTH  asc
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"want to get last 12 months from current date"*? Do you want every date between today and  2019-09-20 in a dataset?

Comment: Use `datediff` function.

Comment: @Larnu.. she wants _past dates_..

Comment: @Larnu want to get last 12 months from current date means 21-sep-2018 to 01-sep-2017 as sep-2018 = 1,aug-2018 = 2,jul-2018 = 3......sep-2017=12

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit unclear on what your range means.  It is not exactly 12 months.  But, I suggest that you use *dates*:

```
with months as ( 
      select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -1)) as yyyymm
      union all 
      select  dateadd(month, -1, yyyymm)
      from months m
      where yyyymm >= dateadd(-13, month, getdate())
     ) 
Select m.yyyymm, coalesce(sum(BillAmount), 0) as Collection,
       coalesce(Sum(AdultsQty + ChildQty), 0) as PaxTotal
from months m left join
     CouponData cd
     on edate >= m.yyyymm and edate < dateadd(1, month, m.yyyym)
group by m.yyyymm
order by m.yyyymm;
```

Comment: @gordon  error:'eomonth' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @aparnarai . . . `eomonth()` has been in SQL Server for many years:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Answer (score 0):

```
with totals as
(
  Select month(edate) as [month], 
    Sum(BillAmount) as bamt, 
    Sum(AdultsQty+ChildQty) as qty
  from CouponData
  Where edate >= dateadd(year,-1,getdate())
  group by month(edate)
)
select [Month],Isnull(bAmt,0) as Collection, qty as PaxTotal
from totals
order by [Month];
```

To have all months:

```
WITH totals
AS (SELECT MONTH(edate) AS [month],
           SUM(BillAmount) AS bamt,
           SUM(AdultsQty + ChildQty) AS qty
    FROM CouponData
    WHERE edate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY MONTH(edate))
SELECT m.mno AS [Month],
       ISNULL(bamt, 0) AS Collection,
       ISNULL(qty, 0) AS PaxTotal
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (1),(2),(3),
        (4),(5),(6),
        (7),(8),(9),
        (10),(11),(12)
        ) m (mno)
    LEFT JOIN totals t
        ON t.month = m.mno
ORDER BY m.mno;
```

Comment: when i have no data available in month(4) then month 4 should be  0????

Comment: @aparnarai, no then month 4 should not exist. If you want all months to exist then you can simply join with (values (1), (2), ... (12)) as months.

Comment: @aparnarai, added all months for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can't work just with months, you need to consider the year too

```
with yearlist as  
( 
select MONTH(GETDATE()) + 12 * year(GETDATE()) as MONTH 
union all 
select  yl.MONTH - 1 as MONTH 
from yearlist yl 
where yl.MONTH  - 1 >= MONTH(GETDATE()) + 12 * year(GETDATE()) -12 
) 
Select  month /12 as 'year', month % 12 as 'month',(Select IsNull(Sum(BillAmount),0) from CouponData Where month(EDate)+ YEAR(EDate) * 12 = YL.month) 
as Collection,(Select IsNull(Sum(AdultsQty+ChildQty),0) from CouponData Where month(EDate) + YEAR(EDate) * 12 = YL.month) 
as PaxTotal  from yearlist YL order by MONTH  asc ;
```

Comment: your ans is very useful for me  but the problem is i am getting month like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12  can i get like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,11,10,9 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get date range by using following query.replace start date.

```
DECLARE @Joiningdate DATE
Declare @StartDate DATE= cast('2017/09/01' as datetime) 
Declare @EndDate DATE=getdate()

SET @StartDate = dateadd(DAY,-365 ,getdate()) 
print @StartDate
;with DateRange As
(
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @StartDate),'' as NoOfday
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
)select * from DateRange
```